# No bugs in Java or XML code, but app crashes on launch

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I'm building a project app from a course. It ran and launched successfully in the previous version but after I copy pasted some code by the instructor in the earthquake_list_item.xml file , the app refused to launch both on the emulator and the physical device. There are no visible redlined errors or bugs that Android Studio shows me. I have checked the logcat and there are tons of errors, none of which I am able to understand. Please help.

This is the earthquake_list_item.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/magnitude"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/magnitude_circle"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="8.9" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location_offset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorEarthquakeDetails"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="30km S of" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/primary_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorEarthquakeLocation"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            tools:text="Long placeholder location that should wrap to more than 2 lines of text" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorEarthquakeDetails"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="Mar 6, 2010" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorEarthquakeDetails"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="3:00 PM" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

These are some of the errors in the logcat:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context must contain application context.
        at com.miui.analytics.internal.policy.h.<init>(SourceFile:7)
        at com.miui.analytics.internal.policy.h.a(SourceFile:5)
        at com.miui.analytics.AnalyticsCore.getClientExtra(SourceFile:2)
        at com.miui.analytics.internal.util.g.b(SourceFile:2)
        at com.miui.analytics.internal.util.g.a(SourceFile:4)
        at com.miui.analytics.internal.LogEvent.a(SourceFile:40)
        at com.miui.analytics.internal.LogEvent.<init>(SourceFile:42)
        at com.miui.analytics.internal.collection.a.b(SourceFile:15)
        at com.miui.analytics.internal.ApkReceiver$1.run(SourceFile:6)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Edit: I have found the problem and the solution, it was due to an xml file where I used selector instead of shape. Thank you to everyone who tried to help!

Comment: `No bugs in Java or XML code` there's a big difference between a runtime and a compile time exception. just because your app compiles, doesn't mean it's going to work as you expect it to. writing : `thrown new RuntimeException()` will also compile, but when you run it, well, that's a different story :)

Comment: consider adding the activity class code

Comment: Do you have all the values like font family in your specific folders and have you tried your code by removing this xml.

Comment: Yes, I have the fonts in their respective folders. The old xml I used is not working after I added this xml.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the context variable in your onCreate for the main activity at least, try this in your onCreate method of the launcher activity `context = activityName.this;`

Comment: keeping context like this is usually a terrible idea and is just unnecessary, everywhere you're going to pass that variable, you could literally just pass in `this`

Comment: I haven't touched android in a long time sorry, but the gist of my answer was to tell OP that he probably forgot to initialise context in his activity, since we can't see it.

Comment: `since we can't see it.` can't see it, can't answer it :) you're (basically) guessing at this point, so until OP includes enough info to show what's causing this problem, we can't really answer it

Comment: Yeah, I am guessing, an  educated guess though.

Comment: I have added the activity code, please help guys.